# Show alert for HTML5 required field validation for no longer visible input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a multiple step form, so when I finally come to the submit button, many of the required inputs are no longer visible for the user, therefore the HTML5 alert can't be apreciate by the user. There's a way to show an alert telling what input is incomplete?

Comment: can you post some html so we can review it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript example:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("The form is incomplete");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp